# 500 Internal Server Error - Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects

Tags: php, apache2

i've setup my server and tried to access the site and get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Ich checked my logs and found following errors. I don't have any clue, why i get the error. I am working with CodeIgniter.

This are the error logs:

```
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.722508 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21444] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.722568 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21444] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723514 2020] [core:error] [pid 21444] [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723537 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3833): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00121: r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723542 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723546 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723642 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723653 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723658 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723664 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723669 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723674 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723680 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /paulshop/index.php, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
[Thu Oct 01 19:24:45.723685 2020] [core:debug] [pid 21444] core.c(3840): [client 31.17.253.157:34572] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /favicon.ico, referer: http://sneakerstore.tk/en/home
```

And this is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /paulshop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /paulshop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And that is the website configuration:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/paulshop

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    LogLevel debug

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
<Directory /var/www/paulshop>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This class calls the url:

```
<?php

class Web_welcome extends CI_Controller{

    function index()
    {
        $property = $this->Property->get();
        list($lang, $country) = explode('_', $property[0]->lang);
        
        header('location:'.base_url().$lang.'/home');
        exit;
    }

}
```

This is the Base Url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

Maybe someone know, how to help me.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your code is causing an infinite redirect loop. Id start by examining the routing for the page you're trying to hit. If there's a login mechanism, Id also look at any related routes, controllers, and middleware to see if there's some improperly configured conditional statement in there somewhere

Comment: I edited my post above, maybe you know how to fix?

Comment: Can you remove `RewriteBase /paulshop/`?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't fixed.